# Show that $ 7\mid (a + 3) $

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

> Being $ a $ and $ b \in \mathbb {Z} ^ {+} $ and $ 2560a = 10 ^ b $,
>   show that $ 7 \mid (a + 3) $

$a=5^8*10 \equiv  2560 \equiv 5$ Does it serve as a counterexample?

or

$256a =10^{b-1}$
$2^8a= 2^{b-1} \cdot b^{b-1}$

$a+3 \equiv 0 $ (mod 7)

$5^8+3 \equiv 0$ (mod 7)

$(-2^8)+3 \equiv 0$ mod 7

$256 + 3 \equiv 0$ mod 7

$ 259 \equiv 0$ mod 7

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! A counterexample to what?

Comment: @Bernard Thank you! To say which question is wrong. She is?

Comment: I doesn't appear that the proposition is true, and $a=5^8*10$ is indeed a counterexample.

Comment: The assertion to be proved?

Comment: Exact! Does the statement seem wrong to you?

Comment: @Sullo Welcome to Math SE. Your counter-example is valid, but your question text has several issues which makes it hard to read & follow. For example, with $2^8a= 2^{b-1} \cdot b^{b-1}$, it appears on the same line as the equation before it, so it appears to be one long equation. You should put a blank line in between the two of them to make this clear. Also, the $b^{b-1}$ factor should be $5^{b-1}$.

Comment: Hi! This is not my first post, I made two more profile cancellations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes $a=2 \times 5^9$ serves as a counterexample. BUT your reasoning why it is a counterexample is not a well-written proof. Here is how I would do it:

First note that $2560 a = 10 \times 2^8 \times 2 \times 5^9 = 10^{10}$. So $2560a$ is indeed of the form $10^b$ for $b=10$.

So now it suffices to show that 7 does not divide $a+3$. To this end, note that $a = 10 \times 5^8$, and that $5^8 \equiv_7 4$ whereas $10 \equiv_7 3$ so $a = 5^8 \times 10 \equiv_7 4 \times 3 \equiv_7 5$. So $a+3 \equiv_7 1 \not = 0$. So indeed, 7 does not divide $a+3$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   2560a &= 10^b \\
   5a &\equiv 3^b \pmod 7 \\
   a &\equiv 3^{b+1} \pmod 7 \\
   a+3 &\equiv 3^{b+1}+3 \pmod 7 \\
\hline
   3^{b+1}+3 &\equiv 0 \pmod 7 \\
   3 \cdot 3^b &\equiv 4 \pmod 7 \\
   3^b &\equiv 6 \pmod 7 \\
   b &\equiv 3 \pmod 6 &\text{See table below}\\
   a &\equiv 4 \pmod 7 &\text{See table below}
\end{align}

\begin{array}{|r|rrrrrr|}
   \hline
     b \pmod 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
   3^b \pmod 7 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 5 \\
     a \pmod 7 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\
   \hline
\end{array}

Since $a \not \equiv 4 \mod 7$, then $7 \not \mid a+3$.

Answer (score 1):

If 7|(a+3) then $a+3\equiv 0 \pmod 7$

Let $a = 5^9\cdot 2$

$5^9\cdot 2+3\equiv 5^3\cdot 2 + 3 \pmod 7$ by Fermat's Little Theorem.

$253\equiv 1 \pmod 7$

Comment: So is the statement true?

Comment: No, because 7 does not divide $a+3$ it leaves a remainder of 1.